# Firebase validate rule regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I cannot get this to work in the Firebase Simulator and I don't understand why. I am making a "favorite" button on my page with a counter that keeps track of the amount of times it was favorited. I want to store the amount in the firebase database. So here are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "favorited": {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val().matches(/[0-9]/) && newData.val().length < 10",
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Writes should be a integer which can only contain 0 to 9 and be less than 10 characters.

I've tested it with the following JSON data on the following path:

```
/favorited/
```

--

```
{
  "foo": 123
}
```

This gives a write error on the validation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a regular expression on a number, not a string. And numbers don't have a `length` property, either.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex):

> Regular expression literals can be used to validate client supplied strings. Use `string.matches(/pattern/)` to test if a string adheres to a regular expression pattern.

You could use:

```
newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < 1000000000
```

As `1000000000` is the smallest number with 10 digits in it.

Comment: Aha I see. But this still gives me a write error, look:
http://baasdesign.nl/images/firebase.png

Or must the key also be a number now?

Comment: That's because you are writing an object - `{ "templateFavorite": 123 }` - and it's failing the `isNumber` validation. Try writing a number - like `123` - or update your rules to include the `templateFavorite` child.

Comment: Awesome, now I understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you!